# Compile a Module wich has a loop with undetermined bound

Tags: compile, infinite-loop

Suppose I have such a module as below:

```
test[int_] := Module[{m},
  m = Table[i, {i, 1, 10}];
  Do[m[[i]] = i*i, {i, 1, int}];
  Return[m]
  ]
```

The bound for `Do` loop is not determined until an argument is given to the test. The argument must be between 1 and 10 in this mini example. It works fine:

```
test[10]
(*{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}*)
```

Now, I want to compile it:

```
test2 = Compile[{{iter, _Integer}}, test[iter], 
  "RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
  Parallelization -> True]
```

executing this returns:

```
test2[10]
CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}
```

So, it evaluates `test2` uncompiled.

Then, I tried to use `Evaluate`:

```
test3 = Compile[{{iter, _Integer}}, Evaluate[test[iter]], 
  "RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
  Parallelization -> True]
```

The compiling returns:

```
Do::iterb: Iterator {i,1,iter} does not have appropriate bounds. >>
```

and if I run compiled version using `Evaluate` it returns:

```
test3[10]
(*{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}*)
```

It won't execute the `Do` loop.

How can I compile a `Module` which has a loop with the upper bound as a variable?

### Edit

I changed the code to see how the answer below works:

```
test[int_] := Module[{m, n},
  m = Table[i, {i, 1, int}];
  n = Table[i*j, {i, 1, int}, {j, 1, int}];
  Do[m[[i]] = Tr[n.n], {i, 1, int}];
  Return[m]]

test3 = Compile @@ (Hold[{{iter, _Integer}}, test[iter]] /. 
    DownValues@test)

test[200]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.104010, Null}*)

test3[200]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{6.565657, Null}*)
```

Compiled version is much more slow.

Comment: `Tr` is not compiled, but results in a call to `MainEvaluate`.

Comment: OK. I just to put it there to make the calculations longer so that I can use `AbsoluteTiming`.

Answer (score 2):

```
test3 = Compile @@ (Hold[{{iter, _Integer}}, test[iter]] /. DownValues@test)
```

Comment: Could you please check my edited question?

Comment: @yashar As mentioned by Michael E2 above, that's mainly because `Tr` isn't compiled. Something like `test[int_] := Module[{m}, m = Table[i, {i, 1, 2 int}]; Do[m[[i]] = i*i, {i, 1, int}]; Return[m]]` and `test3[10^4]; // AbsoluteTiming` is enough to show the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example could be just as easily achieved with `Table[i*i, {i, 1, iter}]`, which compiles.

```
test1[int_] := Module[{m},
  m = Table[i, {i, 1, int}];
  Do[m[[i]] = i*i, {i, 1, int}];
  Return[m]
]

test2[int_] := Table[i*i, {i, 1, int}];

test3 = Compile[{{iter, _Integer}}, Table[i*i, {i, 1, iter}], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Note how I've modified your function, `test1`, because `m` needs to be same size as `int`, which in your case is only true for `int = 10`. Now time them...

```
Do[test1[1000], {1000}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.98 seconds *)

Do[test2[1000], {1000}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.015 seconds *)

Do[test3[1000], {1000}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.006 seconds *)
```

Looking at your second example, by considering what the `Do` loop is doing...

```
test1[int_] := Module[{m, n}, m = Table[i, {i, 1, int}];
  n = Table[i*j, {i, 1, int}, {j, 1, int}];
  Do[m[[i]] = Tr[n.n], {i, 1, int}];
  Return[m]]

test2[int_] := Module[{n},
  n = Table[i*j, {i, 1, int}, {j, 1, int}];
  ConstantArray[Tr[n.n], {int}]]

test3[int_] := Module[{n},
  n = Outer[Times, Range@int, Range@int];
  ConstantArray[Tr[n.n], {int}]]
```

...a significant speed-up can be achieved.

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
test1[200]; // AccurateTiming
(* 0.059 seconds *)

test2[200]; // AccurateTiming
(* 0.00098 seconds *)

test3[200]; // AccurateTiming
(* 0.00038 seconds *)
```

I presume that the example codes are different to your actual problem. Given the performance of the `Do` loop shown here, the question you need to ask yourself is **"Is a `Do` loop the best way to go for my problem?"**

Comment: I need `Do` loop. At each iteration there are some step by step calculations. Each step gives the input for the next step. The code I brought here are intended to show my problem . My actual code is more complicated than that.

Comment: *"Each step gives the input for the next step."*, in which case, have you looked at `Nest` or something similar? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html, which is compilable...